# How to access and add/modify controls in MainWindowTitleBar

Tags: visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-extensions

I'm writing extension for Visual Studio 2019 and I want do add or modify some controls that are in MainWindowTitleBar (compact menu option is enabled). How can I do that? Is there a service for that?
All sources about extensions focus on adding new toolboxes or menu items or use specialized services/interfaces to do certain thing but none of them talk about modifying existing interface.

Comment: Hi friend, any update for this issue? Please check if Sergey's answer helps to resolve this issue. Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [System.Windows.Media.VisualTreeHelper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper?view=netframework-4.8) to find desired Visual Studio controls and then manipulate them as regular WPF controls.